Processing problem port detection to connect HC-05
I can connect my HC-05 with android and i try to do it on windows thru Processing.
so i made a small code to see an try analyse the problem
then i have some trouble: port com is found by Serial.list(), but when i try to connect i have error "port not found"
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;


String string;
void setup(){
  println(Serial.list());
    String portName = Serial.list()[4]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
    port = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
    //port.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {}

and Processing response:

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
COM3 COM4 COM5 COM6 COM7 COM8 COM10 COM11
RuntimeException: Error opening serial port COM7: Port not found
RuntimeException: Error opening serial port COM7: Port not found
RuntimeException: Error opening serial port COM7: Port not found

here info gave by windows 10:

Is somebody could help me to understand what happen and how to solve this ?

Please see if you are able to run hc-05 example code found here: https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-hc-05-bluetooth-module-tutorial/ . On my system I had to change the port from 'com5' to 'com6', otherwise I got a 'port not found' error.

I have a different output with Windows 11 and only see "com6". Not sure how you have all of those com ports on your system. Try using printArray() instead of println() for the Serial.list; it's an array of serial ports (only one on my system). What type of prototype board do you have the hc-05 connected to?  Also change the '4' to a '0', ie Serial.list()[0] to use the main usb port.

It seems HC05 is connected, so i have to switch off Bluetooth on my PC and switch it on to be able to connect my sketch...
